# Spring MVC editable table (Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-rest

I have 2 entities - **Invoice** and **InvoiceProduct**. Invoice class has a field List of InvoiceProduct because Invoice has @OneToMany mapping on InvoiceProduct.

I want to send the List of InvoiceProduct to Thymeleaf with with editable fields with a Submit button. When I click on Submit button, the new edited List should be returned to the controller. However, I am able to send the list to the view, but when I send the edited list to controller, it is being passed as 'null'.

update-invoice.html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/api/invoice/saveInvoice}" th:object="${invoice}" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>PID</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr th:each="temp : ${invoice?.invoiceProducts}" >

                <td><input name="invoiceProducts[${tempStat.index}].productId" th:value="${temp.productId}"/></td>
                <td><input name="invoiceProducts[${tempStat.index}].quantity" th:value="${temp.quantity}"/></td>
                <td><input name="invoiceProducts[${tempStat.index}].price" th:value="${temp.price}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

InvoiceController:

```
@PostMapping("/saveInvoice")
public String postInvoice(@ModelAttribute("invoice") Invoice invoice) {
        
    logger.info("invoice products " + invoice.getInvoiceProducts());

    return "dummy";
}
```

What else do I need to add so that my update-invoice.html passes the list to my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below as an example for thymleaf:-

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/users/}" th:object="${userInfo}" class="col card p-3 mb-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input id="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" required type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role">Role</label>
        <select id="role" required th:field="*{role}" class="form-control ">
            <option value="" hidden>Select a role</option>
            <option th:each="role : ${T(com.springhow.examples.springboot.thymeleaf.domain.entities.Role).values()}"
                    th:value="${role}"
                    th:text="${role}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create User">
</form>
```

and into Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String createUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute UserInfo userInfo) {
    UserInfo user = userService.createUser(userInfo);
    return "redirect:/users/";
  }
```

Comment: the use case you provided is for selecting an element from a list, isn't it ?

Comment: Its about creating an user from thymleaf html using controller